# TypeConverter() has private access in TypeConverter error with Room in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I've integrated *Room* in my project. In this project some classes are in Kotlin and some are in Java. After I converted my Java file to Kotlin using Android Studio <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> combination, I've started facing this error:

> TypeConverter() has private access in TypeConverter

in the generated java class, at this line:

```
private final PointOfInterest.TypeConverter __typeConverter_5 = new PointOfInterest.TypeConverter();
```

But `TypeConverter` in `PointOfInterest` class is public.

Comment: Can you add your `PointOfInterest` class with `TypeConverter`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I my particular case, I converted my Java file to Kotlin using android studio ctrl+alt+shift+k key combination. What android studio did is that, it converted my `class TypeConverter` classes to type of `object TypeConverter` and I just couldn't figured out why my code stopped working. So, I manually changed `object TypeConverter` to `class TypeConverter`.

*One more point regarding conversion to Kotlin:* In case of Parcelable class, kotlin converted file in android studio doesn't add @JvmField on CREATOR field. So, you'll have to add it `@JvmField val CREATOR` manually to ensure proper working of Parcelable classes.

Answer (score 33):

> Don't change the `object` keyword to `class` (as the accepted answer suggests). The [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) guarantees the Singleton pattern.

After automatics conversion of `TypeConverter` java file to kotlin file, you should mark all inner converter functions with [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods) so *Room* can use them as regular static functions.

Take a look at the official [Android Architecture Components samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components), specifically the [GithubTypeConverters.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/db/GithubTypeConverters.kt). Also, [this discussion](https://gist.github.com/tinmegali/d4a477785f01e57066915a44543db6ed) can be useful. And this is my `DateTypeConverter.kt`:

```
object DateTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toDate(timestamp: Long?) = timestamp?.let { Date(timestamp) }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toTimestamp(date: Date?) = date?.time

}
```

Comment: `@JvmStatic` was the essential part (which makes sense). Thanks